How to create a one-finger-drag gesture for an entity as used in ARQuickLook?
While previewing a model in ARQuickLook, I can rotate it in each direction using a one-finger-drag gesture (see pic). As the ARQuickLook is not customizable (can't delete the buttons etc.), I don't want to use it. But I would like to use such a gesture on my model entity.
Unfortunately, within the gestures available for the installGestures(_:for:) there is only a multitouch rotation gesture, a pinch gesture for scaling and a single touch pan gesture for moving along the plane. So nothing that I am looking for.
How do I create such a gesture ? Or maybe there is some way to apply it to the entity ?

